# Batch script with PowerShell commands is not running as intended

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm having a little problem with a script (thanks for the script, sir Jubjub Bandersnatch) that is not running as intended. The script is intended to define an execution policy for the OS and, after setting it, executing a .ps1 script wich intalls [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 7.0.

```
cls
Powershell -noexit -command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Force}"
Powershell -File c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
```

The problem is, it sets an Execution policy with success but after it, the script won't open the .ps1 file. And, another thing that I thought of, people in the company will download this script to different locations, and how do I set a generalized desktop? Like, I'll put  a guide together with the files asking to extract the files on desktop, but how can I tell the script the files will be on their desktop (read: diferent users will need this) without having to modify the script?

**EDIT1:** The first problem was solved with a simple " Start " in front of each line. And I think I might solve the second problem just putting:

```
powershell -file c:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
```

**EDIT2:** I was right, the " %USERNAME% solved it.

Comment: ` cls
Powershell -noexit -command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Force}"
powershell -file c:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1 ` worked ^^

Comment: I think you should remove -noexit from the first line

Comment: Done it, now we don't have a cmd window after doing what we needed to do. Thanks ^^

Comment: Two suggestions. 1. If you want to set an ExecutionPolicy for all users and you have an Active Directory domain, you should set it using Group Policy, unless you want users to be able to later change to setting you give them. If it's defined by GP, not only are the changes propagated more reliably, users can't change it. 2. For the path of the Desktop, use `%homepath%\Desktop` instead of `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop`. That will work across different versions of Windows. Microsoft has changed the default location of user profiles a couple of times.

Comment: If you don't want to set the machine's ExecutionPolicy permanently you can launch powershell with **-ExecutionPolicy remoteSigned**. May make more sense if your organization is sensitive about what users can do on their desktops.

Comment: Why run PowerShell through a shell script at all? Just run the script directly from the PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

(Question solved by OP edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **EDIT1:** The first problem was solved with a simple " Start " in front of each line. And I think I might solve the second problem just putting:
>
> `powershell -file c:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1`
>
> **EDIT2:** I was right, the `" %USERNAME%` solved it.